# From 1D gaussian to 2D gaussian

Tags: calculus, image-processing

I read this:

> The Gaussian kernel for dimensions higher than one, say N, can be described as a regular product of N one-dimensional kernels. Example:
>
> g2D(x,y,$\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$) = g1D(x,$\sigma_1^2$)g2D(y,$\sigma_2^2$)

saying that the product of two 1 dimensional gaussian functions with variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ is equal to a two dimensional gaussian function with the sum of the two variances as its new variance.

I tried to deduce this by using:

g1D(x,$\sigma1^2$)g2D(y,$\sigma2^2$) = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}$ = $\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2}e^{-(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}+\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_2^2})}$

but I fail to obtain

$\frac{1}{2\pi(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)}e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2\sigma_1^2 + 2\sigma_2^2}}$

which is equal to g2D(x,y,$\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$).

Someone know how to get there?

Answer (score 1):

Your first expression,

$G(x,\sigma_1^2) G(y,\sigma_2^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}$ = $\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2}e^{-(\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}+\frac{y^2}{2\sigma_2^2})}$

is a correct anisotropic 2D Gaussian. The expression you are trying to obtain,

$\frac{1}{2\pi(\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)}e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2\sigma_1^2 + 2\sigma_2^2}}$

is not (it’s an isotropic Gaussian). There is no way you can go from the one to the other. However, one can incorrectly match the two expressions by creating a new coordinate system that is a scaled version of the original one, in such a way that the Gaussian is isotropic in the new coordinate system. [The other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1375591/414894) does this. But that is not useful.

It seems that OP is confused about the combination of the variances. The **convolution** of two 1-dimensional Gaussian functions with variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ is equal to a 1-dimensional Gaussian function with variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$. There is no such expectation for the multiplication of Gaussians (in fact, when multiplying them, assuming the same orientation and the same mean, the resulting variance is **smaller**, not larger.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: You see in the exponential that we have
$$ \exp \left ( - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \right )=\exp \left (  \frac{-x^2 }{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) } \right )\exp \left (  \frac{- y^2}{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \right )  $$
The normalization hanging around should be
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi ( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) } $$
as you've seen...but under the change of variables
$$ z_1 = \frac{ \sigma_1x}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}}  \quad \& \quad z_2 = \frac{ \sigma_2y}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}}  $$
What do you obtain? Also note that
$$ 2 \pi = \sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{2 \pi} $$
Edit: We see that
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi ( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \exp \left ( - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \right ) dxdy = $$
$$= \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi ( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 )} }  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left ( - \frac{x^2 }{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \right ) dx \right] \left [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi ( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 )} }   \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left ( - \frac{y^2 }{2( \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 ) }  \right )dy  \right]$$
$$ =\left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\sigma_1 }  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left ( - \frac{z_1^2 }{2 \sigma_1^2   }  \right ) dz_1 \right] \left [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }\sigma_2 }   \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left ( - \frac{z_2^2 }{2\sigma_2^2  }  \right )dz_2  \right] $$

Comment: Using your hint still doesn't give me the correct normalization. Preferably, I would like to go from g1d*g1d to g2d and not the other way around. Could you give me the full derivation?

Comment: What does $dxdy$ become under the change of coordinates I just suggested ?

Comment: Also, if you want to go the other direction, just write the change of variables I gave in terms of $z_1,z_2$

Comment: Why do you ask for dxdy, as there is no integration involved? I'm not able to find out the derivation myself with these hints so it would be great if you could give the full derivation.

Comment: Oh, you should re-read your notes...there is implicitly an integral hanging around in that statement...it is literally just the change of variables I've written.

Comment: It's just fact $$\exp(ax+by)=\exp(ax)\exp(by)$$

Comment: I suggest looking up how to change variables ( jacobian stuff). With the exponential, there are lots of werid change tricks.

Comment: Also, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: No, I understand the math, I don't understand the *answer*. You bent the meaning of $x$ and $y$ in the OP to get two equations to match, but the two equations should not be matched to start with, they result from a misunderstanding of OP.

Comment: Ohhh, I see your confusion now. I'd read up on probability distribution functions. You'll see that probabilities are just integrals over distribution functions. Thus people sometimes talk about distributions being the same... but they mean that in the sense that the probabilities are the same. Not the functions themselves.

Comment: I don’t know how your last statement relates to this. You should begin by assuming I understand statistics and mathematics, and stop telling me to read up on stuff. It would make this discussion easier for both of us. You should also add `@Cris` to your comment to ping me, I saw your last comment by chance.

Comment: note that OP’s second expression uses the same x and y as the first expression. The change of variables makes the forms match, but not the function. The first Gaussian is anisotropic, the second is not.